# betti-numbers of Gin(I), generic initial ideal of $I$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

[here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870898918886) in the paper *Ideals with Stable Betti Numbers* there is a theorem that I can't uderstand it, both in details (which highlighted) and sketch of the proof of (b):

[image]

[image]

can you help please?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at Theorem 1.31 of [this](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0346-0329-4_2) notes by Mark Lee Green.

Comment: thank you Abdul Basit; + . but i cant get answer: why the two Gin are equal and why we may assume... . what is sketch of the proof of (b)?